# Import Hotmail friends to Twitter?

Tags: twitter, outlook.com

How can I import my Hotmail friends over to Twitter? The old importer doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Twitter have [removed this functionality](http://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/108-finding-following-people/articles/29869-hotmail-msn-contact-importer-is-no-longer-available) but a workaround is available here;

http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/06/06/how-to-find-windows-live-hotmail-contacts-on-twitter/

> Twitter allows you to import gmail contacts.
>
> Gmail allows you to import MSN contacts.
>
> Hence, you can indirectly import MSN contacts in twitter by importing them first on your gmail account.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice hack :))))

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Hotmail import is back: http://twitter.com/#!/who_to_follow/import

[image]